# Ajax call returing ReferenceError: variable is not defined while using jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following input with name and id as consultdate which selects a jQuery datepicker date value in format dd/mm/yyyy.

I have an ajax call which when placed runs a query on mysql db and i need to store it as a php session value. The code is as follows:

Ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#consultdate').change(function() {
consultdate = $('#consultdate').val();
userid= '<?php echo $user_id;?>;'
cat = '<?php echo $category;?>;'
dataString = "consultdate="+ consultdate +"&userid=" + userid + "&cat=" + cat;
alert(consultdate);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'qry/date-time_qry.php',
data: {dataString : dataString },
success: function(data)
{
//alert(data);
}
});
});
</script>
```

and php page date-time_qry.php:

```
if (!isset($_POST["userid"]) || empty($_POST["userid"]) ||  !filter_var($_POST["userid"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) 
{
$error[] = "Sorry, Invalid Operations!";
}
else
{
$user_id = strip_tags(trim($_POST["userid"]));
}
if (!isset($_POST["consultdate"]) || empty($_POST["consultdate"])) 
{
$error[] = "Sorry, Invalid Operations!";
}
else
{
$consult_date = strip_tags(trim($_POST["consultdate"]));
}
if (!isset($_POST["cat"]) || empty($_POST["cat"])) 
{
$error[] = "Sorry, Invalid Operations!";
}
else
{
$cat = strip_tags(trim($_POST["cat"]));
}
//DB Query
include_once('../inc/connect.inc.php'); 
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT consult_time_utc FROM booking WHERE user_id = :id && consult_date =:consultdate && user_category = :category");
$stmt3->bindValue(':id', $user_id);
$stmt3->bindValue(':category', $cat);
$stmt3->bindValue(':consultdate', $consult_date);
$stmt3->execute();
$stmt3->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$consult_time_UTC = array();
while($r = $stmt3->fetch())
{
$consult_time_UTC[] = implode(',', $r['consult_time_utc']);
}
$_SESSION['timeutc'] = $consult_time_UTC;
```

Update:
I used data: {consultdate : consultdate, userid : userid, cat : cat }, instead of datastring

Current issue is timeutc|a:1:{i:0;N;} session value in place of 12:30 PM.

**Update:**
implode outside the while loop corrected the issue.

```
$consult_time_UTC = implode(',',$consult_time_UTC);
```

Sorry, wonder why people are adamant on down voting questions??

Comment: Missing quotes around the php output to make it a javascript string

Comment: `cat = "<?php echo $category;?>";`

Comment: have you heard of "indentation"?

Comment: @charlietfl Okay..got it..Thank you..Let me check success output too..

Comment: @@charlietfl But Receiving empty array timeutc|a:0:{} in session.

Comment: seems like i need to explode the datastring and create array of post values.

Comment: Okay..i used data: {consultdate : consultdate, userid : userid, cat : cat }, as it seems the better way.

Comment: It's strange without calling ajax how can you get the response? is your ajax request working ?

Comment: @Ahmed Ginani Yes i got it working. But current issue is regarding blank array

Answer (score 0):

Missing Quotes

Hi you are missing quotes for category, as it is a string you need to assign the value in quotes

**Replace this**

```
cat = <?php echo $category;?>;
```

**To**

```
cat = "<?php echo $category;?>";
```

Comment: @Sawood I have corrected that already. Issue is regarding blank array in php while loop after implode.

Comment: timeutc|a:1:{i:0;N;} session value in place of 12:30 PM.